# How do you find gradient of an undefined vector?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have the function:

$$f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x} \vec{x}^T$$

All we know is that $\vec{x}$ is a vector. Shouldn't I know how many values ($x,y,z$ etc.) my vector holds? I haven't done gradient with a vector function before, so a hint in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is an operation that measures the increasing rate of a given function and is denoted by $grad f(\vec{x})$ or $\nabla f(\vec{x})$ and defined by $[i\partial_x+j\partial_y+k\partial_z]f(\vec{x})$, where we considered $f(x)$ in $R^3$; $i,j,k$ the unit vectors; and $\partial_x$ the derivative in $x$. It works like a derivative in n-dimensional spaces. For example, consider the function:
f((x,y))=2x+3y, than the gradient of this is given by $\nabla f((x,y))=2i+3j$.    This idea can be extended to $n$ dimensions, assuming the following format:
Given $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n):=e_1x_1+e_2x_2+\ldots+e_nx_n$ and $f(\vec{x})$, then $\nabla f(\vec{x})=(e_1\partial_{x_1}+e_2\partial_{x_2}+\ldots+e_n\partial_{x_n})f(\vec{x})$, where  $e_l$ works like arrow matrices, l=1,2,\ldots,n.

Now, let us see your function:  $f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}\vec{x}^T$.
If $\vec{x}$ is represented like above by an arrow matrix, then $\vec{x}^T$ will  be a column matrix and your function is a scalar function -- and the proposed computation above can be done --, i.e., for each point $\vec{x}$ in the space $R^n$ we have a scalar value of $f(\vec{x})$. In this way:
$$f(\vec{x})=(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2+\ldots+(x_n)^2 
$$
$$\Rightarrow \nabla f(\vec{x})=e_1\partial_{x_1}[(x_1)]^2+e_2\partial_{x_2}[(x_2)]^2+\ldots+e_n\partial_{x_n}[(x_n)]^2=2[e_1x_1+e_2x_2+\ldots +e_n x_n]
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\nabla f(\vec{x})=2\vec{x}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated explanation! Your answer was a good compliment to John's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Write $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. Then your function $f$ is just
$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)^2 = x_1 ^2 + \ldots + x_n^2
$$
Now
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = 2x_j
$$
so the gradient, which is a vector of all the partials, is just
$$
\nabla f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (2x_1, 2x_2, \ldots, 2x_n) = 2x
$$
and it turns out that the number $n$ of components of $x$ was irrelevant: no matter how many components there are, you have
$$
\nabla f (x) = 2x.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The part where you redefined x and the function made it clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also calculate directly with ordinary rules:

$$f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x} \vec{x}^T =\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}$$

$$\nabla f=\frac{df}{d\vec x}=1\cdot\vec x+\vec x\cdot1=2\cdot\vec x=(2x_1,2x_2,...,2x_n)$$